#  How to fill in a border in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I know how to create a border, How do I fill in the rest inside the border with a different color? Here's what I have so far:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:6px outset orange;">text</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
background:#fff
```

or any color;
and one more advise never use inline css for optimal output use external CSS

```
<div id="something">text</div>

#something
{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
 //likewise
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/XVDkS/

Explanation: it adds box shadows (at least 2 of them) after the border (with 0 blur). Manipulate the number of shadows & the width of them according to your need. You can as well use blurring, if required. Read [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) for more details on box-shadows.

It's a CSS3 solution, so old IE versions won't play nice (unless you do dark magics on it).

Answer (score 1):

use the background property, for example:

```
background:#ccc;
```

which would leave your code looking like this:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:6px solid orange; background:#ccc;">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a background this will help

CSS

```
backgound:black;
```

HTMl with CSS

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:6px outset orange;background:black;">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groove or ridge in place of outset,

See here is some examples for this on `W3schools`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=none

or if you want 2 borders and a different border then you try this

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000">
    <div style="width:190px;height:90px;border:5px solid orange">
    <div style="width:188px;height:88px;border:1px solid #000">
    test
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SPhec/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:6px outset orange;background:#000000">text</div>
```

use css background property